# NSLog statements not showing for iOS 10 in apple Configurator

Tags: ios, nslog, apple-configurator

I have an app built using XCode 7.3 and it works fine with iOS 10.
But, the NSLog() statements that I had used for debugging earlier aren't showing up.
I could see them earlier inside apple configurator and now all I can see are so many kernel process messages.
The same is still working when I test an iOS 9.x device.
Kindly, update if this is resolved or is there any workaround.

Answer (score 2):

If you have use XCode 8 then solution is below...

Goto -> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments -> Environment Variables

In the Environment Variables: Perhaps you once added the Name "OS_ACTIVITY_MODE" and the Value "disable" and check it. But this way can lead to the Console cannot NSLog when the real iPhone debugging.

I solve it in this way: Only add "OS_ACTIVITY_MODE" and check it（Don't add the Value）

You can also see in below image

[image]

For XCode 7 You don't have any solution.

**Alternative for this problem:** I can't see NSLog output in real iOS 10 device neither. If you're using real devices, you can open Devices window from Xcode (Shift + Command + 2) and see device logs there, but it's hard to look at your app's logs because the console shows logs from system and all apps.

**NOTE: If you check the [Xcode 8 beta release notes](https://developer.apple.com/download/), you'll find that it says:
When debugging an app running on Simulator, logs may not be visible in the console. Workaround: Use command + / in Simulator.app to open the system log in the Console app to view NSLogs. (26457535)**

Comment: I cannot test on a simulator and I have to test on a real device . So , is this way appropriate to see NSLogs ?

Comment: I can't see NSLog output in real iOS 10 device neither. If you're using real devices

Comment: You have to upgrade your XCode version

Comment: So the NSLogs of a real device isn't possible to be seen now ? What am doing now is am writing all NSLogs to a file and then see that file to debug but this is taking a lot of time and I don't think this is the right way either .

Comment: If you will upgrade your XCode version then it's Work like charm and First solution work for you